# Unable to hide the UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uicollectionview

In the method `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` I have the following code:

```
collectionView.hidden = (currentSection.numberOfObjects < 1)
```

I am expecting the entire collection-view to hide, but I get the background color where the collection-view would be visible.  I also have an IBOutlet that is the collection-view which I tried and I get the same results (e.g., `self.collectionView.hidden = (etc.)`

Is there more that needs to be hidden??

NB. I am able to successfully do this with a `UITableView`.

Comment: I found my problem.  I had to put "hidden" in viewWillAppear of the UIViewController, then let the reloadData's  invocation of the collectionview "unhide" or "hide again" depending on the data change.  Apparently, the reloadData may not invoke collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection under some initial conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the container views to "hidden" in viewWillAppear of the UIViewController, then let the reloadData's invocation of the collectionview "unhide" or "hide again" depending on the data change. Apparently, the reloadData may not invoke `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection` under some initial conditions.